# Extracting basic statistics using aggregate inside a function in R

Tags: r, function, aggregate

I have created a function to extract the basic statistics like Mean,median , mode , SD, Var based on what the user wants. Eg. If the user wants to see only mean ,only mean should be calculated. So the statistics are passed as arguments.

The code is

```
  countfunc<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby,AggValue){
  S1=select(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby)
  S2=unique(S1)

  str(S2)
  stackval5<-aggregate(Groupby~Xaxis+Color,data=S2,FUN=AggValue)
  return(stackval5)
}

countfunc(sbarr,"workclass","sex","age","mean")
```

Sample data :

```
> dput(head(S1,20))
structure(list(workclass = structure(c(8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c(" Federal-gov", 
" Local-gov", " NA", " Never-worked", " Private", " Self-emp-inc", 
" Self-emp-not-inc", " State-gov", " Without-pay"), class = "factor"), 
    sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c(" Female", 
    " Male"), class = "factor"), age = c(39L, 50L, 38L, 53L, 
    28L, 37L, 49L, 52L, 31L, 42L, 37L, 30L, 23L, 32L, 40L, 34L, 
    25L, 32L, 38L, 43L)), .Names = c("workclass", "sex", "age"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

But when i run the function , it is throwing an error as "In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA" even though the "age" column is in Int, tried with Numeric conversion as well.
str of my DF

```
'data.frame':   886 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ workclass: Factor w/ 9 levels " Federal-gov",..: 8 7 5 5 5 5 5 7 5 5 ...
 $ sex      : Factor w/ 2 levels " Female"," Male": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ age      : int  39 50 38 53 28 37 49 52 31 42 ...
Xaxis Color Groupby
1 workclass   sex      NA
```

If i hard code the values (aggregate(age~workclass+sex,data=S1,FUN=mean), it is working as expected.It would a great help if you guide or share some thoughts on what i am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the desired output? If you use `identity` instead of `mean`, you'll see the argument passed to `mean` is definitely not numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
countfunc<-function(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby,AggValue){
  S1=select(dset,Xaxis,Color,Groupby)
  S2=unique(S1)

  stackval5 <- aggregate(S2[[Groupby]], list(S2[[Xaxis]], S2[[Color]]), FUN = AggValue)
  names(stackval5) <- c(Xaxis, Color, Groupby)
  stackval5
}

countfunc(sbarr,"workclass","sex","age","mean")
          workclass     sex      age
1           Private  Female 33.60000
2  Self-emp-not-inc  Female 43.00000
3           Private    Male 39.42857
4  Self-emp-not-inc    Male 42.33333
5         State-gov    Male 34.50000
```

What you were doing wrong was the formula. `aggregate` was looking for the values of the variables `Xaxis`, `Color` and `Groupby`, which were, respectively, `"workclass"`, `"sex"`, and `"age"`. Since the value `"age"` is neither numeric nor logical, it would return `NA`. (It would do `mean("age")` and return `NA`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ..U r always there for me :)  Cheers.. If it is not too much to ask , Could you please share what was i did wrong ? How that error appears .. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Oh..My bad , I thought directly placing the arguments would also bring the values.it seems ,I missed that one. much appreciated :)